# Why do these PSD differ?

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I have a circular 2D convolution (the underlying function $f$ only depends on radius) that I apply to a 2D gaussian white noise map $M$.

I am then comparing :

- the PSD (Power Spectral Density) along one axis of the 2D FFT of $f$, meaning :

a) computing the 2D FFT of $f(r)$ sampled over a significant 2D domain

b) extracting a 1D line out of this 2D FFT

- the PSD (Power Spectral Density) over a line of $f*M$, meaning :

a) computing the convoluted 2D map $f*M$

b) computing the PSD over an axis of this resulting map

And the resulting PSDs don't match. Yet it is my understanding they should.

Here is the resulting plot (Matlab source provided below) :

[image: PSD mismatch]

- First, is this normal ?
- Second, can you explain what is happening here and potentially suggest corrections ?

```
rng(0)

Te=0.05; % sampling time
ctn_noise_psd=1; % Bilateral PSD of requested continuous noise
sbd=sqrt(ctn_noise_psd/(2*Te)); % std of corresponding discrete noise

n1d=2000;
noise2D=randn(n1d,n1d*2)*sbd;

% Convolution to apply
% --------------------

% Continuous
tau=1;
fconv=@(r) exp(-(r/tau).^2/2);

% Numerical matrix

% we build the matrix of ranges wrt to its center
rmax=5*tau;ir=ceil(0.5*rmax/Te);rmax=2*Te*ir;
X=ones(2*ir+1,1)*linspace(0,1,2*ir+1);Y=X'; % adim : de 0 à 1
Rquart=rmax*sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2); % de 0 à rmax
R=[Rquart(end:-1:2,end:-1:2) Rquart(end:-1:2,:);Rquart(:,end:-1:2) Rquart]; % rmax around 0

% and the convolution matrix is
mconv=fconv(R);

% 2D FFT of this convolution matrix
ltf=2^(1+nextpow2(size(mconv,1)));
freqs_fft=(0:ltf/2)/(ltf*Te);
fft2D=fft2(mconv,ltf,ltf); % fft 2d

% "Cut" of the FFT along one direction
fftcut=fft2D(1:ltf/2+1,1:ltf/2+1); % 1D cut from fft2D
dsp_fft=Te^4*abs(fftcut(1,:)).^2; % corresponding PSD


% Application of the convolution
% ------------------------------
irp=ceil(5*tau/Te);
%residu=conv2fft(noise2D,mconv,'same');
residu=conv2(noise2D,mconv,'same');
residu=residu(irp+1:end-irp,irp+1:end-irp);
[nl,nc]=size(residu);

% Frequency analysis of the result
% 
[Pxx,w]=pwelch(residu(1,:));
ratio=2*pi*Te;
freqs_ech=w'/ratio;
dsp_echs=zeros(nl,length(freqs_ech));
dsp_echs(1,:)=Pxx'*ratio;
for kl=2:nl
    dsp_echs(kl,:)=pwelch(residu(kl,:))'*ratio;
end
dsp_ech=mean(dsp_echs);

% Figure
% ------
close all
figure('Name','2D Example')
loglog(freqs_fft,sqrt(dsp_fft)*sqrt(ctn_noise_psd),'r');grid on;hold on;
loglog(freqs_ech,sqrt(dsp_ech),'b');
xl=get(gca,'XLim');set(gca,'XLim',[max(0.001,xl(1)) xl(2)])
yl=get(gca,'YLim');loglog(1/Te*[1 1],yl,'r--')
legend('PSD (1D-line cut from FFT2D)','PSD (on an axis of residuals)')
title({'';'\surd PSD (./\surdHz)'})
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');ylabel('\surd PSD (./\surdHz)')
```

Comment: What does 'PSD' mean in this context?  Does PSD stand for "probability distribution function"? Or "positive semidefinite"?  Are you  asking why Matlab cannot reproduce the formulas in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Relation_to_the_Fourier_transform_(circularly_symmetric_case) ?

Comment: @kimchilover : PSD = Power Spectral Density (added in the main question). I am asking why the two results aren't equal, as it is my understanding they should (the PSD across any axis deduced from the 2D FFT should match the observed PSD along one axis of the test data). i am asking whether I am wrong in assuming that (in which case, what is the correct expected relation between the two). In both cases, I am asking if someone can explain to me what is going on (either why I am wrong in assuming this, or why is my test incorrect).